# undefined variable stopping if else statement from working

Tags: laravel

In my app, users can create personal 'groups'. Each user has a `user profile` and I show the groups that they've created on their profile like this `{{ ucwords(trans($groupCreated->group_title)) }}` which works great.

I want their group title to be inside a green box, and to show a grey box if no groups have been created by the user.

Here's the full code for the green box:

```
@foreach($user->groupsCreated as $groupCreated)<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><a href="{{ route('groups.show',$groupCreated->id)}}"> {{ ucwords(trans($groupCreated->group_title)) }}</a></div>@endforeach
```

Here's what I want to show if no groups created:

```
<!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted pb-3">Deleted groups are not shown</small>
<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
This user has no active groups</div> -->
```

Here's my `if` `else` statement to make this happen:

```
@if ($groupCreated())

<small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted pb-3">Deleted groups are not shown</small>
@foreach($user->groupsCreated as $groupCreated)
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
<a href="{{ route('groups.show',$groupCreated->id)}}"> {{ ucwords(trans($groupCreated->group_title)) }}</a>
</div>
@endforeach

@else

<!-- Show if no groups created -->
<!-- <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted pb-3">Deleted groups are not shown</small>
<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert">
This user has no active groups</div> -->

@endif
```

The error I get is `Undefined variable: groupCreated`

Here is my GroupController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Group;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

// All Groups pages require login except 'show'
class GroupsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'show']);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $groups = Group::where('created_by_user_id', auth()->id())->get();

        return view('groups/index', compact('groups'));
    }

    /**
     * Store the group that a user has joined in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function join(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user_id = auth()->id();
        $group = Group::find($request->get('group_id'));

        if (!$group->isLoggedInUserJoined())
            $group->joinedUsers()->attach($user_id);

        $redirect = $request->get('redirect', 'groups/joined');

        return redirect($redirect)->with('success', 'You joined the group!!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the user from a group that they have joined in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function unjoin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_id' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = Group::find($request->get('group_id'));

        if ($group->isLoggedInUserJoined())
            $group->joinedUsers()->detach(auth()->id());

        $redirect = $request->get('redirect', 'groups/joined');

        return redirect($redirect)->with('success', 'You\'ve left the group.');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function joined()
    {
        //@todo change query to show groups joined
        // $groups = Group::where('created_by_user_id', auth()->id())->get();
        // $groups = Group::with('joinedUsers')

        $groups = auth()->user()->groupsJoined()->get();

        return view('groups/joined', compact('groups'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('groups.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)

    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            'group_description' => 'required',
            'group_date' => 'required',
            'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = new Group([
            'group_title' => $request->get('group_title'),
            'group_description' => $request->get('group_description'),
            'group_date' => $request->get('group_date'),
            'group_time' => $request->get('group_time'),
        ]);
        $group->save();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group saved!!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        // $group = Group::find($id);
        $group = Group::with('createdByUser')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('groups.show', compact('group'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        return view('groups.edit', compact('group'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'group_title' => 'required',
            'group_description' => 'required',
            'group_date' => 'required',
            'group_time' => 'required',
        ]);

        $group = Group::find($id);
        $group->group_title =  $request->get('group_title');
        $group->group_description = $request->get('group_description');
        $group->group_date = $request->get('group_date');
        $group->group_time = $request->get('group_time');
        $group->save();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group updated!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $group = Group::find($id);
        $group->delete();
        return redirect('/groups')->with('success', 'Group deleted!');
    }
}
```

and the Group Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'group_title',
        'group_description',
        'group_date',
        'group_time',
        'created_by_user_id'
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($group) {
            $group->created_by_user_id = auth()->id();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the user that created the group.
     */
    public function createdByUser()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by_user_id');
    }
    /**
     * Get the users that joined the group.
     */
    public function joinedUsers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'group_joined_user', 'group_id', 'user_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
    /**
     * Checks whether the currently logged in user is joined to the group.
     */
    public function isLoggedInUserJoined()
    {
        return $this->joinedUsers()->where('users.id', auth()->id())->exists();
    }
}
```

So, I added the following to Model

```
  /**
     * Fetch the groups created by user
     */
    public function groupCreated()
    {
        return $this->groupCreated()->where('groups.show', auth()->id());
    }
```

But the error is:

> Undefined variable: groupCreated

Any help?

Comment: Which line and file is the error coming from?

Comment: What are you returning to your view where your `@if else` statement is?

Comment: none of your controller method send `$user` to the view.

Comment: Which view should I send the user to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably `@if ($groupCreated())`. What is this line supposed to do?

If you just want to check if the user has any groups you can use `@if ($user->groupsCreated->count() > 0)`.